# What does this do? const { foo = "bar" } = "baz"

Tags: javascript

Saw this code recently and can't seem to find the answer on google, so here we are.

The actual code was from a webpack config:

```
const {
  NODE_ENV = 'production',
} = process.env;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+equal+sign+in+curly+brackets) of [Javascript object bracket notation ({ Navigation } =) on left side of assign](/q/26999820/4642212) and [Javascript Object destructuring and default parameters combined](/q/51697735/4642212). See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Answer (score 3):

Destructuring with a default value.

```
const { NODE_ENV } = process.env;

// is roughly:

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV
```

And together

```
const { NODE_ENV = 'production' } = process.env;

// is roughly (probably presence check is more sophisticated):

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 2):

This mean you assign default value to variable. look example below.

```
const { foo = "bar" } = "baz";
// foo -> "bar"


const { foo = "bar" } = { foo: "baz" };
// foo -> "baz"
```